# SignalR & Android, what are my options?

Tags: android, signalr

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC app that is consumed by both by JavaScript in the browser and by a native Android app, and I wish to use SignalR. This is of course no problem in the browser, but I do not know how to interface from the Android app.

Are my only options:

1. Find a pre-existing Android SignalR library. or
2. Write custom code to interface with the server side SignalR interface?

Comment: And now almost 2 years later https://github.com/SignalR/java-client !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unaware of any Java based implementation that you could use in an Android application right now. So I think you're looking at option #2.

Java certainly has the core functionality needed to to be able to communicate with at least the long-polling transport implementation of SignalR pretty easily. You'd just be looking at combining `HttpClient` with `org.json`.

Comment: Also, consider using MonoDroid http://www.gregshackles.com/2012/07/using-signalr-in-monotouch-and-mono-for-android-apps/

Comment: Hah, just saw that post this morning too and was coming back to update my answer. Definitely a good option if you're not afraid to go the .NET/C# route.

Answer (score 10):

I was also searching for a SignalR-client for Android, but i didnt find one so I started to develop one by myself. You can checkit out at https://github.com/erizet/SignalA. <del>Curently it's more like a proof-of-concept than a finnished library.</del> 
It's now updated to protocol version 1.2 which is used in the 1.0 release of SignalR.

Comment: Sounds good. Is it usable? As in, are the parts that are implemented working?

Comment: Hey Erik, I am in need of SignalR client and I saw SignalA but the problem is that it does not (yet) support Hubs. Can you advice me what are my options?

Comment: I find that SignalA is very buggy - it is the only client that I am using to connect to my SignalR server that has issues. Plus it only has long polling, which isn't the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If HTML5-based Android app is an option, you can try using native SignalR JavaScript client. Works flawlessly.

Comment: you have used the signalR js client on android through a normal webview?  There is a project where I want to try the same and would love to hear feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Host a hidden webview in your application and use the script bridge to talk to it. Use the javascript signalr libraries in your webview.

Comment: our results with this have not been great. doing it this way seems to cause many connection/reconnection/disconnection issues

Comment: @Julien did you ever discover why you were getting these kind of issues? Because the SignalA library above isn't working for me so I was thinking about a solution like this.

Comment: @RobbyCohen it works. there are some strange issues which we haven't fully figured out yet but it is a feasible solution

Comment: @Julien could we discuss this more in a chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/34096/signala-alternative?tab=general